Overlapping Error Bars Using Only One Data Set Not Multiple
I have a scatter plot with error bars. The x-values for some of the points are the same so it is hard to see which error bars correspond to what point. I have looked up that people will add trans1 and trans2, but that works for two data sets and I only have one. My issue stems from overlapping x-values. Any ideas how to show which point goes with which. Maybe changing colors?
x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
y = [my_values]
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=e, ecolor='g', marker = 'o', linestyle = 'None', capsize=5)
plt.show()

